# Why is this null?

Tags: unity, c#

Every enemy object has an ItemDrops script and every item has a DisplayItemLabel script.

In SpawnItem(), you'll see that I'm trying to set itemNameText.text to "hello"; I'm using a string literal to eliminate some variables, but eventually I'd do something like SpawnItem(Item item) and set itemNameText.text to item.itemName;

The Problem:

In the SpawnItem function, When I debug the variable 'drop', I get the item game object. When I debug the variable 'displayItemLabel', I get the DisplayItemLabel component attached to drop. No issues here. But, when I debug 'displayItemLabel.itemNameText', I get Null. Why is this happening? I've commented out the line where I set the text in SpawnItem, but I get the exception regardless. I've also tried rearranging the order of the lines in SpawnItem and I still get the exception. I've tried removing the SetActive(false) stuff in DisplayItemLabel, and the same problem occurs. Lastly, I've tried to set the reference of ItemNameText more directly (without a dependency on itemLabel). I'm not really sure where to look next.

Attached to each Enemy game object:

```
public class ItemDrops : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform itemPrefab;
    private EnemyHealth enemyHealth;

    private float originToGroundDistance;
    private Vector3 offset;

    private bool itemDropped;
    private bool numberGenerated;
    private float randomNumber;

    private ItemData itemData;
    public string nameOfDroppedItem;

    void Start()
    {
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();

        itemData = GameObject.Find("Item Manager").GetComponent<ItemData>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Initialized in Update instead of Start because enemy floats to 1.083333 on the Y-axis some time after Start
        originToGroundDistance = transform.position.y - 0.25f;
        offset = new Vector3(0f, originToGroundDistance, 0f);

        if (enemyHealth.isDead && !itemDropped)
        {
            if (!numberGenerated)
            {
                RandomNumberGenerator();

                //Debug.Log(randomNumber);

                if (randomNumber < 1)
                {
                    SpawnItem();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        numberGenerated = true;

        randomNumber = Random.value;
    }

    private void SpawnItem()
    {
        itemDropped = true;

        GameObject drop = Instantiate(itemPrefab, transform.position - offset, Quaternion.identity).gameObject;
        DisplayItemLabel displayItemLabel = drop.GetComponent<DisplayItemLabel>();

        Debug.Log(displayItemLabel); // SHOWS DisplayItemLabel SCRIPT
        Debug.Log(displayItemLabel.itemNameText); // BUT THIS IS NULL
        Debug.Log(displayItemLabel.itemNameText.text); // NullReferenceException

        //displayItemLabel.itemNameText.text = "hello";
    }
}
```

Attached to each Item game object:

```
public class DisplayItemLabel : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private GameObject itemLabel;
    public Text itemNameText;

    void Start()
    {
        itemLabel = transform.Find("Canvas/Item Label").gameObject;
        itemNameText = transform.Find("Canvas/Item Label/Item Name Text").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        //itemNameText = itemLabel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();

        itemLabel.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ClampLabelToItem();
    }

    private void ClampLabelToItem()
    {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f, 16f, 0f);

        Vector3 desiredPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position) + offset;
        itemLabel.transform.position = desiredPosition;

        itemLabel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try `Debug.Log`ing said `itemNameText` at the end of DisplayItemLabel/Start - that might give you some insight on what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Start()` is queued for execution, instead of being executed during `Instantiate`. If you want an initialization function to run during `Instantiate`, you need to use `Awake()`. And if I recall correctly, even `Awake` will only run if the gameObject is instantiated in an enabled state. Or you could write your own initialization function, which you call manually after `Instantiate`.

Personally, I sometimes to work around this by using a [Factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) and an [Object Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), and thus initialize objects without relying on Unity's Awake/Enable/Start functions.

Comment: The Unity docs say "Awake is called when the script object is initialised, **regardless of whether or not the script is enabled**" (helpfully, [they say this in the documentation for Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), not for Awake...) So it should work fine for this purpose.

Comment: Or you can use propetries instead of fields and do lazy initialization when first used.

Comment: @DMGregory the "script", not the gameobject the script is attached to.